# Unanswered questions: Please upvote and accept useful answers, and have a look at the unanswered tab

Tags: discussion, answers, voting, accepted-answer

At the moment, we have an 86% answer rate. Right now, there's 134 questions with no answers at all, and 19 questions with no upvoted answers.

[image]

Sure, the answer rate is not the only thing we should be concentrating on, because we want *quality* answers. But it's also important that people usually get an answer to their question when they ask them.

---

**Questions with no accepted or upvoted answers**

You can see below, from the 5k tools, that our voting is largely on the increase, which is great!

[image]

Of course, that's not to say that you should upvote or accept **bad answers**.

If a question cites case law or statute, I encourage you to look at it and verify the claims. Just because something *seems fair*, doesn't mean it *is legal*.

If it checks out, upvote it. [You get up to 40 votes a day, and up to 30 of them on answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/260340).

If it's your question, I'd say wait a little bit, then accept the answer if it answers your question. This might encourage an extra answer or two.

Voting up useful answers, and accepting them, helps the site in two ways:

- People feel *good* when people recognise that they've provided a good answer.
- Increased reputation means that people can do more to help moderate the site, which means that bad questions will get closed faster, good questions that are closed in error will get reopened faster, and bad answers get deleted faster.

---

**Questions with no answers**

- After 122 days in beta as of right now, there are 134 questions with no answers, and [107 questions which are likely eligible](http://data.stackexchange.com/law/query/368582/find-candidates-for-revival-badge) for the [Revival](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/badges/64/revival) badge.

  > Answer more than 30 days after a question was asked as first answer scoring 2 or more

  Remember that you can earn this badge even if there are other answers, as long as yours is the first to have a score of 2 or more.
- There's also the [Necromancer](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) badge:

  > Answer a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

  Remember that you can earn this no matter how many other answers are on the question, regardless of their score.

---

**Does anyone see any patterns in the unanswered questions?** Let's try to stay on the front foot and keep ahead of this. We want to try to answer as many questions as we possibly can. Also, shiny badges!

Comment: Good post. How do you access those stats? Is that a mod only feature?

Comment: Ooops...scratch that. When I clicked on the graph it explained that you need 5k rep.  On another note Jim, are the unanswered questions from all time, or is there some expiration if a Q doesn't get answered after a certain timeframe? How long has this site been up?

Comment: These are all-time; and no, unanswered questions don't age away.

Comment: And the site's been up for about 126 days, I think.